# flask: error: unrecognized arguments: db migrate

Tags: python, flask, flask-migrate

I have a flask app and have managed to run db init on it. Now I'd like to add a column to the db and thus migrate it. When I type `flask db migrate` in my terminal (from within my virtualenv) I get an error:

```
usage: flask [-h] [--port PORT]
flask: error: unrecognized arguments: db migrate
```

This is strange because `flask db --help` does give me the menu options for flask db. Here is my app's `__init__.py` file :

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import os
from flask_migrate import Migrate

app=Flask(__name__)

SECRET_KEY = os.urandom(32)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = SECRET_KEY

basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///'+os.path.join(basedir, 'data.sqlite')
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)
```

This is my `models.py`:

```
from healthycart import db
from datetime import datetime


class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64))
    email = db.Column(db.String(64))
    zipcode = db.Column(db.String(64))
    meal_plan = db.Column(db.Integer)
    date_joined = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)

    def __init__(self, name, email, zipcode):
        self.name = name
        self.email = email
        self.zipcode = zipcode
        self.meal_plan = None
```

The other columns are already there - I just want to add the "zipcode" column.

Comment: Can you show your `Models.py`?

Comment: In fact, did you use the command `flask db init` before migrating? As in, your post just says you ran `db init`, no mention of `flask`. I am not assuming you did not do that, but it is worth being sure.

Comment: Thanks for helping, @JakeJackson. I already ran `flask db init` (and `flask db upgrade`) in the past - the database is there and working. I'll include my models.py in the question.

Comment: Have you set `FLASK_APP` properly? As in `export FLASK_APP=main.py`? (Change `main.py` to whatever your equivalent file is called.)

Comment: Assuming you have set `FLASK_APP`, can you run `flask db init` again and add the output to the question?